# Setting a marker at users current position with Google Maps API?

Tags: javascript, api, google-maps

I want to set a marker at the users current position in the following script.

Can anyone supply me with the right code, that actually works with this script?

I have tried some from the Google documentation, without any luck.

THANKS

```
    <html>
    <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no"/>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

    var showPosition = function (position) {
    var userLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude);
    // Do whatever you want with userLatLng.
    }

    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition); 

    var directionDisplay;
    var map;


function initialize() {
    directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer();
    var copenhagen = new google.maps.LatLng(55.6771, 12.5704);
    var myOptions = {
        zoom:12,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
        center: copenhagen
    }

    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);
    directionsDisplay.setMap(map);
    }


    var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();



    function calcRoute() {
    var start = document.getElementById("start").value;
    var end = document.getElementById("end").value;
    var distanceInput = document.getElementById("distance");

    var request = {
        origin:start,
        destination:end,
        travelMode: google.maps.DirectionsTravelMode.DRIVING
    };

    directionsService.route(request, function(response, status) {
        if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
            directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
            distanceInput.value = response.routes[0].legs[0].distance.value / 1000;
        }
    });
    }


    </script>

    <title>Distance Calculator</title>

    <style type="text/css">

            body {
                font-family:Helvetica, Arial;
            }
            #map_canvas {
                height: 50%;
            }
    </style>
    </head>
    <body>

    <body onload="initialize()">
    <p>Enter your location and desired destination to calculate the distance</p>
        <div>
            <p>
                <label for="start">Start: </label>
                <input type="text" name="start" id="start" /><br />

                <label for="end">End:</label>
                <input type="text" name="end" id="end" /><br />

                <input type="submit" value="Calculate Route" onclick="calcRoute()" />
            </p>
            <p>
                <label for="distance">Distance (km): </label>
                <input type="text" name="distance" id="distance" readonly="true" />
            </p>
        </div>
        <div id="map_canvas"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the geolocation capability in HTML5 like you had attempted to, but you need to make sure that you don't ask for the geolocation before the map is initialized. So, move your call to `navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition);` to the end of your `initialize()` function.

Also, you'll need to create a new marker for the user's position, and assign the map to that marker:

```
var showPosition = function (position) {
    var userLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude);
    // Do whatever you want with userLatLng.
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: userLatLng,
        title: 'Your Location',
        map: map
    });
}
```

Comment: Finally! Thank you very much! 

I don't know if this is too complicated, but is it possible to use the current location as starting point in the distance calculator?

Comment: Sure, you would make that location the origin of the directions query. P.S. If this answer solves your problem, please choose it as the correct answer.

Comment: Can you tell me where exactly I have to change the script to do that?

Comment: That'd really be a separate question/answer.

Comment: I created a new question, feel free to have a look at it :) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12923905/using-current-location-as-starting-point-in-distance-calculator-google-maps

Answer (score 1):

You can get the user's location(approximate) from their IP address.  Check out these resources:

http://www.geoplugin.net/php.gp

http://isithackday.com/hacks/geo/yql-geo-library/

http://www.maxmind.com/app/geolitecity (Downloadable database)

Once you get the latitude and longitude from one of the above sites,

```
var location = new google.maps.LatLng(40.779502, -73.967857);
marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: location,
        map: map
    });
```