# How to add a marker to Google map of user's location?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I currently have a map with one marker of a desired location. I'm now hoping that when a user shares their location a marker will be added to the google map (I then plan to use this to calculate a route between them, but not for now). I will add my relevent code below as for some reason when I share my location no marker is added to the map.

JSLint errors: https://gyazo.com/78c773119fee621fead77df0fcb81a5b

Any help would be greatly appreciated thank you.

HTML:

```
<div id="map">
</div>
```

JS:

```
function initMap() {
    var chestersLoc = {lat: 52.19147365, lng: -2.21880075},
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
            zoom: 16,
            center: chestersLoc
        });
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: chestersLoc,
            map: map
        });
}

var showPosition = function(position) {
    var userLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude),
        marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: userLatLng,
            title: 'Your Location',
            draggable: true,
            map: map
        });

}

navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition);
```

Comment: may this link helpful http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12923486/setting-a-marker-at-users-current-position-with-google-maps-api

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**EDIT**

I've created a JSfiddle with code updates here: https://jsfiddle.net/iamjpg/b6rv7Lc1/1/

```
// Map instance
var map;

// Markers array so map can show both markers with best view.
var markers = [];

// Init map
var initMap = function() {
  var chestersLoc = {
    lat: 52.19147365,
    lng: -2.21880075
  };
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    zoom: 16,
    center: chestersLoc
  });
  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: chestersLoc,
    map: map
  });

  // Push marker to array
  markers.push(marker);
}

// Show the users position
var showPosition = function(position) {
  var userLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude);
  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: userLatLng,
    title: 'Your Location',
    draggable: true,
    map: map
  });

  // Push marker to array
  markers.push(marker);

  // Create bounds object, loop over markers, set best map view.
  var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
  for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
    bounds.extend(markers[i].getPosition());
  }

  // Set best map view for markers.
  map.fitBounds(bounds);
}

function errorHandler(error) {
  console.log('Geolocation error : code ' + error.code + ' - ' + error.message);
}

initMap();

navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition, errorHandler, {
  enableHighAccuracy: false,
  maximumAge: 60000,
  timeout: 27000
});
```

------ OLD POST -----

I would recommend the following changes to your code - this will return an error message if the navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition() isn't working:

```
function errorHandler(error) {
  console.log('Geolocation error : code ' + error.code + ' - ' + error.message);
}

navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition, errorHandler, {
  enableHighAccuracy: false,
  maximumAge: 60000,
  timeout: 27000
});
```

For example, in Chrome, if your site is served on `http` and you're sourcing Google Maps with `https` there could be problems - more information here: https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2016/04/geolocation-on-secure-contexts-only

Comment: current console error https://gyazo.com/12c9bc271a8dbcc3d5a3ce436ec9fae0

Comment: `map` is undefined. In your initMap, using the design pattern you've implemented, you'll want to make that variable available outside of the scope of the `initMap` function. An easy, yet not desirable way to do that is assigning the `map` variable to the window object. `window.map = ...`

Answer (score 0):

be sure you call the initMap

assign proper style to map id

```
 <div id="map" dtyle="width: 400px; height: 400px;></div>
```

declare map at window level

```
var map;  

function initMap() {
    var chestersLoc = {lat: 52.19147365, lng: -2.21880075},
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
            zoom: 16,
            center: chestersLoc
        });
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: chestersLoc,
            map: map
        });
}

var showPosition = function(position) {
    var userLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(position.coords.latitude, 
                              position.coords.longitude);
       var  marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: userLatLng,
            title: 'Your Location',
            draggable: true,
            map: map
        });
       map.setCenter(marker.getPosition());

}



// ***** assuming you have a callbak for initMap  
// ***** otherwise uncomment the line below
// google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);

navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition);
```

Comment: I have this line in my html head <script async defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=&callback=initMap"></script> The map works fine and the first marker is there it's just the user's marker isn't being added after the location is shared

Comment: ok then the initMap is invoked .. i have updated  the answer for a var marker inside showPosition .. and setCenter to new location

Comment: Unfortunatley still no change and the center doesn't move. I assume I should add a semi-colon to end of var userLatLng line?

Comment: yes semicolon added  ... and check in browser  console for error

Comment: Current console error https://gyazo.com/12c9bc271a8dbcc3d5a3ce436ec9fae0

Comment: Yeah here's a screenshot of updated code https://gyazo.com/71a9163ede2d52be72e70125e79f9fbf

Comment: are you connected  to internet ?

Comment: Yes but i'm only running it locally, however it's putting a marker on the other location so that should be fine right?

Comment: have you removed the keyword var leftside of map inside tne initMap function ? the var declaration for map must be only at top level outside any function